# Stability of the RC Circuit with Two Capacitors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

I want to find poles and zeros of the circuit shown below. So I can determine stability of the system.

[image: schematic]

$$ V_{C1} + V_{C2} + V_R = 0 $$
where $I$ is current of the loop,
$$ V_{C1} + V_{C2} + RI = 0 $$
where $I = C\dot{V}_{C2}$,
$$ V_{C1} + V_{C2} + R(C\dot{V}_{C2}) = 0 $$

I thought that I could determine the stability of the system with using Lyapunov's theorem but as can be seen, there are two unknown variables to be solved. How should I approach this problem to determine stability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation has a problem

$$
-V_{C2} + V_{C1} + V_{R1} = \color{red}{0} \tag{1}
$$

Since $C2$ and the source are in parallel

$$
V_{C2} = 0.8 \tag{2}
$$

Comment: That is right, I edited it.

Comment: @AldrichTaylor Isn't caverac answering your question?  $$0.8 = q/C_1 + Rq',$$ where $q$ is charge.